# Css transition and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I've a message element that I add to my page in a function:

```
 const markup = `<div class="todolist__message todolist__message${status? "--ok":"--err"}">${msg}</div>`;

    elements.tdl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);

    if(fade) {
        const message = document.querySelector('.todolist__message');

        // Change the message opacity
        message.style.opacity = '0';

        // Remove the message element
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.querySelector('.todolist__message').parentElement.removeChild(message);
        }, 2000);
    }
```

and I add the css properties:

```
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s;
```

What I don't understand is why, when I change the message opacity to 0 the transition doesn't seem to work and the element instantly disappears?

I have to rewrite the code, putting the style change in the setTimeout, and add an extra setTimeout for the element removal:

```
const markup = `
    <div class="todolist__message todolist__message${status? "--ok":"--err"}">${msg}</div>
`;

elements.tdl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);

if(fade) {

    setTimeout(() => {
        const message = document.querySelector('.todolist__message');

        // Change the message opacity
        message.style.opacity = '0';

        // Remove the message
        setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('.todolist__message').parentElement.removeChild(message), 2000);
    }, 2000);
}
```

Does anyone mind explaining why the first code block results in the message instantly disappearing, rather than the css transition being applied?

Thanks

** See answer below for a way to remove elements once the animation is complete.

Comment: Try with adding class instead of updating style.

Comment: Yeah, cheers, that's probably better than the 2x timeouts, but still interested in why the above isn't working as I expect?

Comment: Your code is working, see my answer. PS: where did you put this `transition` rule, can you show your css with selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```js
var msg = "hello World";

const markup = `
    <div class="todolist__message todolist__message">${msg}</div>
`;

wrapper.innerHTML = markup;
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {

        const message = document.querySelector('.todolist__message');

        // Change the message opacity
        message.style.opacity = '0';

        // Remove the message
        setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('.todolist__message').parentElement.removeChild(message), 2000);
});
```

```css
.todolist__message {
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<button id="btn">delete</button>
```

Comment: Yeah, it's the first code example that doesn't work, the one without the two setTimeouts :)

Comment: @NickW I think that the problem is that you're adding and instantly removing, there are things in JS related to CSS when you need to run setTimeout(0) so the code run in next event loop because css update happen in JS event loop.

Comment: Hmm, I mean it's good to know i've not missed anything too obvious, and you're probably right - but I'm struggling to see how your code is really any different, will have a play about with it, thanks

Comment: @NickW in my code the remove is in click event so it's not in same time as in your code. If you add setTimeout(0) to your code it should work, because of event loop. Watch this video [Jake Archibald: In The Loop - JSConf.Asia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to apply `opacity: 0` at the same time, you apply the transition.
To `transition` to work; you need to add transition class first and add `opacity` inside setTimeout.

Comment: do you mean because I'm creating the class itself at almost the same time as applying the opacity? The transition is technically already applied before the opacity is set to zero because it's in the css for the element (along with opacity: 1)

Comment: That's same thing. Creating a new element or adding 'class' having `transition` property.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, the second timeout and the removal of the element should be replaced with a transitionend event listener on the element, which calls a method that deletes the element once the animation is complete, rather than syncing the setTimeouts with the animation delay+duration:

```
window.addEventListener(this.whichTransitionEvent(), function(e) {
    if(e.target.classList.contains('todolist__message')) {
        toDoListView.deleteMessage(e.target);
    }
});
```

The delete function:

```
export const deleteMessage = element => {
    if(element) {
        element.parentElement.removeChild(element);
    }
};
```

And David Walsh's function for checking prefixes:

```
whichTransitionEvent() {
    let t;
    const el = document.createElement('fake-element');
    const transitions = {
        'transition': 'transitionend',
        'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
        'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
        'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd'
    }

    for(t in transitions) {
        if(el.style[t] !== undefined)
            return transitions[t];
    }
}
```

I think I've done that right - it seems to be working either way!